# multiarch-support:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.3.6-2) but it is not installable

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, apple-m1

I have this Laravel project (laravel 6) that runs on Docker.

And I got this error:

```
multiarch-support:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.3.6-2) but it is not installable
```

The Dockerfile has this: the full version is found https://pastebin.com/zpjHdBRr

```
RUN curl 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb' --output multiarch-support.deb \
 && apt-get install ./multiarch-support.deb

RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -yq --no-install-recommends install \
        unixodbc-dev \
        msodbcsql17
```

I'm currently running on Mac (M1 chip)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install software built for x86 on m1, which is ARM-based. Just change the amd64 to arm64. Worked for me.
Instead of

[http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb'](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb%27),

use

[http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_arm64.deb'](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_arm64.deb%27).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but there seems to be some problem with 1.4 version
you should consider upgrading it to 1.5

multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb
I have tested with 1.5 and it works fine !

[Link to download 1.5 version](https://pkgs.org/download/multiarch-support)